# JQuery not working on submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to learn some JQuery. I am using an external js to write my code in. It works fine when I call the 2 paragraph functions, but when I call the submit button it just load the page again. 
My code looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>

    <p id="paragraf">This is an internal paragraf</p>


    Another Example:
    <p id="paragraftest">This is the external js script</p>

    <form>
        <input type="text" name="Submit_test">
        <button id="buttontest">Submit</button> 
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryScript/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryScript/hide.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#paragraf').click(function() {
    $('#paragraf').hide();
});

$('#paragraftest').click(function() {
    $('#paragraftest').hide();
});

$('buttontest').submit(function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

/* I have tried with "" and '' in buttontest and test, but still the same */
I have also tried with this, but it is still the same.

```
<form>
        <input type="text" name="buttontest">
        <input type="submit" value="">
    </form>
```

Can anybody see why nothing happens?
Best Regards
Mads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct this syntax:

```
$('input[name=buttontest]').submit(function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

Using a unique ID for the button:

```
$('input#button_id').submit(function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Missing id selector - `buttontest` is the id of the button so you need to use [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) to select it(prefix with `#`)

```
$('#buttontest').submit(function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

Comment: Funny, but this answer is totally incorrect. `#buttontest` is a button and not a form, it doesn't have a `submit` event at all.

Comment: Perfect... thanks a lot everybody. This solved the answer :-)

Comment: @user1883095 In your HTML `buttontest` is a button. If you move this id to a form this will be correct.

Comment: The good thing is that if you give a form an id, then you can have a lot of forms on the page and functions to those forms in your js, or?

Comment: @user1883095 there is nothing wrong with giving the form an id.... only thing to keep in mind is ID of an element must be unique in a page

Answer (score 1):

You should select the button with the following way:

```
$('#buttontest')
```

You hadn't used the #, which is required when we are selecting elements form the DOM using their ids. For sure it was a writing error, since you use this correctly on your other selections.

Answer (score 0):

Submit event is a form event, and you are trying to bind it to a button.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

In generally if you want to submit a form you should use dedicated `onsubmit` form event, **not** `click` event on any button.

Answer (score 0):

It works with this code now:

```
<form id="form">
        <input type="text" name="buttontest">
        <input type="submit" value="submit"> 
    </form>
    <form id="form_1">
        <input type="text" name="buttontest">
        <input type="submit" value="submit"> 
    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    alert("test");
});

$('#form_1').submit(function() {
    alert("test");
});
```